# EF Core tag map UsingEntity, how to prevent it from re-inserting existing relations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use a simple "tag map" system with EF Core 5. As far as I can tell from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) I'm doing it correctly, but I keep running in to the issue that EF tries to re-insert already-existing items into the db and crashing:

> SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: TagMap.FoosId, TagMap.TagsId'.

Here's a full example that generates the problem. The set-up is simple, there is a Foo class with a collection of Tags, and they are mapped with UsingEntity() to the "TagMap" table. It crashes on the second SaveChanges() when it tries to reinsert the first tag:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
> Failed executing DbCommand (65ms) [Parameters=[@p0='1' (DbType = String), @p1='1' (DbType = String)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> INSERT INTO "TagMap" ("FoosId", "TagsId")
> VALUES (@p0, @p1);

How can I get this to work?

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace EfTagTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();

            var tags = new List<Tag>
            {
                new Tag() { Name = "one" },
                new Tag() { Name = "two" },
            };

            var foo = new Foo() { Name = "Foo1" };
            foo.Tags = new List<Tag>() { tags[0] };

            if (File.Exists("ett.db"))
            {
                File.Delete("ett.db");
            }

            using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
            {
                dbContext.Database.Migrate();
            }

            using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
            {
                dbContext.Foos.Add(foo);
                DisplayStates(dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries());
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            foo.Tags.Add(tags[1]);

            using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
            {
                dbContext.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Modified;
                DisplayStates(dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries());
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private static void DisplayStates(IEnumerable<EntityEntry> entries)
        {
            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Entity: {entry.Entity.GetType().Name}, State: { entry.State.ToString()}");
            }
        }
    }

    class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Tags)
                .WithMany(t => t.Foos)
                .UsingEntity(x => x.ToTable("TagMap"));
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=ett.db;");
            optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory);
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll);
        }

        public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
            = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { builder.AddConsole(); });
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The generated db looks exactly like you'd expect:

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "TagMap",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    FoosId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                    TagsId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_TagMap", x => new { x.FoosId, x.TagsId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_TagMap_Foos_FoosId",
                        column: x => x.FoosId,
                        principalTable: "Foos",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_TagMap_Tags_TagsId",
                        column: x => x.TagsId,
                        principalTable: "Tags",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_TagMap_TagsId",
                table: "TagMap",
                column: "TagsId");
```

And the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've run into is utilizing the same object on two different dbContexts (you create it once for the first save, then you destroy it and create a second one...)

> ```
> using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext()) {
>     dbContext.Foos.Add(foo);
>     DisplayStates(dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries());
>     dbContext.SaveChanges(); 
> }
>
> foo.Tags.Add(tags[1]);
>
> using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext()) {
>     dbContext.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Modified;
>     DisplayStates(dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries());
>     dbContext.SaveChanges(); 
> }
> ```

If you only use one dbContext, you won't have to re-attach the "foo" object because changes to it will be tracked after you first attach it with the Add method `dbContext.Foos.Add(foo)`.  Subsequent changes will then be tracked correctly (even after the first `SaveChanges()`) allowing you to make MORE changes and `SaveChanges()` again - **as long as you don't dispose of the dbContext that is doing the tracking.**

So, to correct the quoted code above, use this instead:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext()) {
    dbContext.Foos.Add(foo); // <-- dbContext starts tracking changes to foo here.
    DisplayStates(dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries());
    dbContext.SaveChanges();  // <-- Pending changes saved to datastore.

    foo.Tags.Add(tags[1]); // <-- Oh look, something is changing on a tracked entry!
    
    DisplayStates(dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries());
    dbContext.SaveChanges(); // <-- Pending changes saved to datastore.
}
```

To go above and beyond the question, if you want to manipulate the tags on an existing foo object, you'll need to load it along with it's existing tags and manipulate those:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext()) {
    var myExistingFoo = dbContext.Foos
        .Include(x => x.Tags) // <-- dbContext will track the tags only if you include them.
        .Where(x => x.Id == 12) // <-- Just loading the one with Id = 12
        .First(); 
    DisplayStates(dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()); // <-- No changes yet.

    foo.Tags.Add(tags[2]); // <-- A new tag!
    // foo.Tags.AddRange(newTags); // <-- A whole bunch of new tags!
    // foo.Tags.RemoveRange(foo.Tags.Where(x => x.Name == "Bad Tag")); // <-- Remove one or more tags
    // foo.Tags.Clear(); // Delete all tags
    
    DisplayStates(dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()); // <-- Shows the new tag.
    dbContext.SaveChanges(); // <-- Only the new tag is added.
}
```